# dynamic controller in router zend framework 1.11

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, controller, router

How work multi controller in route?
My route:

```
$router->addRoute(
       'index',
       new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:@action',
           array(
                'lang' => 'en',
               'module' => 'default',
               'controller' => 'index',
               'action' => 'index'
           )
       )
    );
```

This route work with index controller, but not work with auth controller. 
how to work with that route and index auth controller?

My menu item:

```
$this->url(array('controller'=>'Auth','action'=>'index')
```

This menu item, not work.
My complete function _initRoutes()

```
protected function _initRoutes(){

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->addRoute(
            'fullRoute',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:module/:controller/:action',
                    array('lang' => ':lang')
            )
    );
    $router->addRoute(
            'languageControllerAction',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:controller/:action',
                    array('lang' => ':lang')
            )
    );

    $router->addRoute(
       'index',
       new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:@action',
           array(
                'lang' => 'en',
               'module' => 'default',
               'controller' => 'index',
               'action' => 'index'
           )
       )
    );

}
```

I need route for action of controller auth.

Comment: Do you want one route for the `IndexController` and a second route for the `AuthController`?

Answer (score 0):

**Route #1**

This will point `http://yoursite.com/auth` to `default` module, `AuthController`, `indexAction`:

```
$router->addRoute(
       'auth',
       new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
           'auth',
           array(
               'lang' => 'en',
               'module' => 'default',
               'controller' => 'auth',
               'action' => 'index'
           )
       )
);
```

**Route #2**

This will point `http://yoursite.com/` to `default` module, `AuthController`, `indexAction`:

```
$router->addRoute(
       'index',
       new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
           '',
           array(
               'lang' => 'en',
               'module' => 'default',
               'controller' => 'auth',
               'action' => 'index'
           )
       )
);
```

Comment: Now work, but. The url for controller index site.com/en/<controller>/<action>. How hide controller name in url?

Comment: Hi, please look at my updated answer and also respond to the comment under your original question.

Comment: when add the route 1 and route 2 in Bootstrap, all link redirect for site.com/

Comment: I think we are experiencing miscommunication. I can't help you if you don't respond to my direct questions.